# how to remove the error by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form action="line_check.php" name="reg" method="POST" >
        <table border="0" align="center" width="" style="">
            <tr>
                <td align="" width="78">Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" onfocus="document.getElementsByClassName('err1').innerHTML=''" class="inputstyle h" />
                </td>
                <td align="center">Gender</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="gender">
                        <div class="umale">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" checked value="Male">
                            <label>Male</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ufemale">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">
                            <label>Female</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="" width="78"></td>
                <td height="10">
                    <div class="err err1"></div>
                </td>
                <td align="center"></td>
                <td>
                    <div></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="" width="78"></td>
                <td colspan="3">
           <input type="button" name="sub" class="submit" value="" onclick="chk();"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This is my form , if the user click on the submit button and name field is empty then it will show the error in **class name err1**  but if the user click on the name field , I have used **onfocus="document.getElementsByClassName('err1').innerHTML=''"** , it will disappear the error message but its working for id but when i used class name , Its now working 
can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: I couldn't understand your issue… can you add the respective code or a small demo..?

Comment: when name field is empty , my chk function show me the error in class name  err1 . and when   user click on the name field **onfocus="document.getElementsByClassName('err1').innerHTML=''"**     onfocus remove the error message from the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
onfocus="document.getElementsByClassName('err1')[0].innerHTML=''"
```